# Passar Texto+localicação para aplicativo do google maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

Olá, estou fazendo um aplicativo usando apenas: HTML, JS(AngularJS) e CSS. Tenho o seguinte.

A minha localização que é pega pelo aplicativo e um endereço que está salvo no banco de dados, uma string ex: São Paulo, Rua principal 78 - Centro.

Eu quero fazer um botão(Iniciar Trajeto) para por exemplo: Estou no Osasco(seria minha localização atual) e criar a rota até São Paulo, Rua principal 78 - Centro.

Estou usando o seguinte código para abrir o aplicativo do google maps:

```
<div class="meuMapa"> 
<a onclick="javascript:window.open('geo: , ', '_system')> Iniciar Trajeto</a></div>
```

Mas não faço ideia de como passar os parâmetros corretamente, alguém sabe como? Em muitos sites vi que passa a longitude e a latitude, mas no meu caso eu não tenho isso, apenas o endereço que é uma String. Ou se tiver um jeito melhor de fazer isto também aceitaria dicas e links.

Answer (score -1):

Se você possui o endereço, pode obter as coordenadas de longitude e latitude por **Geocodificação**, conforme a documentação da [API de Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro).

Este exemplo demonstra o uso da API em JSON:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Avenida%20Paulista%201000,%20S%C3%A3o%20Paulo
```

Esta é a resposta da requisição:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1000",
               "short_name" : "1000",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Avenida Paulista",
               "short_name" : "Av. Paulista",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bela Vista",
               "short_name" : "Bela Vista",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "São Paulo",
               "short_name" : "São Paulo",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "São Paulo",
               "short_name" : "SP",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Brasil",
               "short_name" : "BR",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "01310-100",
               "short_name" : "01310-100",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Av. Paulista, 1000 - Bela Vista, São Paulo - SP, 01310-100, Brasil",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -23.5647577,
               "lng" : -46.6518495
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -23.56340871970849,
                  "lng" : -46.65050051970849
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -23.5661066802915,
                  "lng" : -46.65319848029149
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJfwcg7cdZzpQR-FIlwhOEYxI",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

O trecho específico abaixo lista as coordenadas de latitude e longitude para o endereço o tipo **ROOFTOP** indica que o resultado retornado é um código geográfico preciso para o qual há informações de localização com precisão de endereço. Estes são os valores que devem ser passados.

```
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : -23.5647577,
           "lng" : -46.6518495
        },
        "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
```

Comment: Murillo, ai bastaria passar as coordenadas aqui 'geo: , ', '_system' que funcionaria? Eu fiz alguns testes comparando no googlemaps do navegador e acaba dando errado, seria algo como 'geo: 0,0 ',' 0,0 ? Obrigado